# Change bar color when condtion is true and change if it false

Tags: pine-script

I am a beginner in programming, I have a question
i want to make an indicator in pinescript
i want to change bar color when condition is true and change when condition is false, but in crossover condition
the point is when a buy signal, the color bar is green until a sell signal and the color turns red

```
linecci0 = 0
linecci1 = -200
linecci2 = 200
cci = cci(hl2,50)
cci1= cci < 200 and cci>-200

opl1 = crossover(cci,linecci2) and vfima > 0
ops1 = crossunder(cci,linecci1) and vfima < 0

// Deternine if we are currently LONG
isLong = false
isLong := nz(isLong[1], false)

// Determine if we are currently SHORT
isShort = false
isShort := nz(isShort[1], false)

// Buy only if the buy signal is triggered and we are not already long
buySignal = not isLong and opl1

// Sell only if the sell signal is triggered and we are not already short
sellSignal= not isShort and ops1

if (buySignal)
    isLong := true
    isShort := false

if (sellSignal)
    isLong := false
    isShort := true


plotshape(buySignal, text="BUY", style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green,textcolor=color.white, size=size.small)
plotshape(sellSignal, text="SELL", style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red,textcolor=color.white, size=size.small)
```

I want to plot the green bar when I buy and it doesn't change until it sells
and thank you if anyone wants to answer

Comment: What do you mean by "plot bar"? Do you want to change the bar color, or background color, or something else?

Comment: i want to change bar color, and sorry about the typo in the title

Comment: I just want to make sure the condition doesn't change until the next signal and between those two signals I want to add another command

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `barcolor()` function to change the bar color.

Here is an example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

ema10 = ta.ema(close, 10)
ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)

bull = ta.crossover(ema10, ema50)
bear = ta.crossunder(ema10, ema50)

barcolor(bull ? color.yellow : na)
barcolor(bear ? color.purple : na)
plot(ema10, color=color.yellow, linewidth=2)
plot(ema50, color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
plotshape(bull, color=color.yellow, size=size.small)
plotshape(bear, color=color.purple, size=size.small)
```

[image]

Comment: yes it changes when only the cross and the bar after it does not change, what I want is the color of the bar to change when the crossover reaches the crossover

Comment: if i use "barcolor" in "if" error will occur "cannot use 'barcolor' in local scope"